# Missing Keyword Error in Oracle SQL Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created my table emp1 which is
create TABLE emp1(

id INTEGER Not NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
fname VARCHAR(20),
lname VARCHAR(20),
salary NUMBER(8,2),
streetadd VARCHAR(20),
city VARCHAR(20),
country VARCHAR(20)
);

and also I have inserted on it

INSERT INTO emp1 values(1,'ahmed','hamza',20000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(2,'Laiba','khaliq',30000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(3,'Anas','Khaliq',40000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(4,'Laiba','Shakeel',50000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(5,'Summer','Shah',60000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(6,'Ali','Haider',70000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');
INSERT INTO emp1 values(7,'Umer','Farooq',80000,'shah faisal colony','karachi','Pakistan');

But Then I want to add a new column on which is auto generated oracle is giving me error which is "missing keyword"
This modification I have to do
ALTER TABLE emp1 add ssn INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1 ) NOT NULL ;

**I just want to know why it is giving me error on modification **

Comment: What version of Oracle? It looks like you might be on 11g or earlier - identity columns were added in 12c. (Also `start with` can't be zero unless you set `minvalue` too - the default for both is 1.)

Comment: The error is clear because such columns don't start with 0, but with 1 or higher. What should be the purpose of starting with 0? Why to use an identity column here rather than a sequence?

Comment: @JonasMetzler - in 12c or later it would get "ORA-04006: START WITH cannot be less than MINVALUE" which is indeed clear; but the OP is getting "ORA-02000: missing ) keyword", which means they are on an earlier version that doesn't support identity columns at all. That's a bit less obvious. (Agree that starting with zero looks odd, but it is allowed if you set `minvalue` to zero too; also meant to point out in my comment that would apply for a normal sequence too.)